# Choosing between `Collection <MyObject>` inside vs outside of `MyObject` class [Java]

Tags: java, collections

What is the best way to store a `Collection<MyItem>` ? This collection is effectively static for current user. Each user can only see their collection. `MyItem` item implements `IItem`:

```
public interface IItem {    
    public Integer getItemID();
    public void setItemID(Integer id);
    public String getTitle();
    public void setTitle(String title);
    /*more getters and setters*/
    public IItem parseServerResponse(String response);
    public int postItem(); //posts this IItem to server, return ok ->200, unauth->401, etc
    public IItem findItem(String[] filters);
    /*more advanced methods*/
}
```

I can store `Collection<MyItem>` elsewhere, but then I can't access private `MyItem` methods from `CurrentMyItems`:

```
public class CurrentMyItems{        
    private final List<IItem> allItemsList;
    public CurrentMyItems(String allItemsServerResponseString){
        JSONArray rawItems = parseResponse(allItemsServerResponseString);
        int arrSize = rawItems.length()+estimateQuantityOfNewItems();
        List<IItem> allItemsList =  new ArrayList<>(arrSize);           
        for (int i = 0; i < Items.length(); i++) {
            allItems.add(i, parseItem(Items.get(i)));
            }               
    }
    /*methods*/
}
```

Or inside of the `MyItem` class (see commented out options):

```
public class MyItem implements  IItem {
    /*
    private final static List<IItem> allItemsStaticList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final static Map<Integer, IItem> allItemsStaticMap = new HashMap<>();   
    private final List<IItem> allItemsList;  //
    private final static Map<Integer, IItem> allItemsMap;
    */
    /*implemented methods*/
}
```

`allItemsStaticList` - stores a static list of all Items. Seems memory efficient, but what if I need to store separate collections of MyItems in future? This is highly unlikely, but still...

`allItemsList` - Same class has two distinct functions. It is either

storing a single Item, in which case `allItemsList/Map = null;`
 or
 `allItemsList = new ArrayList<>();`, while other fields are empty.
 This seems OK, but it breaks the Least Surprise Principle.

Which approach to store a `MyItemCollection` is more natural?

Also, should I store `Item`s as a `Map` or a `List` given that `MyItem myItem = getMyItemByID(int id);` is the main way to access `MyItem`?

---

**Update**

We can implement an `Item` class so that an instance can either hold a collection of `Item` instances or the modeled data, but not both.

```
public class Item {
    private final Map<Integer, Item> itemsMap;
    private final IntegerProperty itemID;  // private final String[] names;

    public Item(){
        itemsMap = new HashMap<>();
        itemID = null; //names = null;
    }

    private Item(Integer id) {           
            itemsMap= null;
            itemID = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id); //names = new String[1];
        }  

    public Item makeGenericItem(){
        return itemsMap == null ? null : new Item(itemsMap.size());            
    }
  // other methods, including getters and setters
}
```

But at what cost?.. This class violates single responsibility principle.

Conclusion - in most cases a Collection of Item instances should be stored outside of Item class.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but how does the location of the `Collection<MyItem>` field affect the accessibility of private methods in `MyItem` from `CurrentMyItems`?

Comment: @ChristophBöhme I want to reduce the method visibility to private if it is only used by `MyItem` and `Collection<MyItem>`. I can do this by placing `Collection<MyItem>` as a field of `MyItem`. If I store `Collection<MyItem>` outside of `MyItem` I have to set scope to at least package private. So the question is __Should I place the collection inside of an Item to reduce visibility of some methods?__

Comment: Don't ask yourself where you should put the list to have access to method but where does instance belong based on the relation with other class. If you put it in `MyItem` directly, is it possible that a `IItem` have `IItem`, since the `MyItem` will have a list of `MyItem` that have a list of `MyItem` that have ...

Comment: @AxelH  I agree. this can be addressed (added to my post below "Update"), but it makes code harder to read/understand. The cost is high while the benefit (change method visibility from package private to private) is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OOP the data elements of an object are also known as *attributes* of the object. So, you should ask yourself whether a collection of items is an attribute of an item or not.

For example, when you assume your items are students. Would you say that a list of students is an attribute of a student? -- Probably not, as a list of students is not part of a student. Instead a student is part of a list of students.

Since a list of students is not an attribute of students in real life, I would not model it differently in code just to make it technically more elegant.

The design of your classes should be driven by the structure of the domain that your are working in. When you need to decide where to put an attribute do not ask "does it make sense to put it here because of the features my programming language offers?" but ask "where does this attribute belongs to in my domain?".